# question on a step used in book solution for PDE using method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

On page 213, from book nonlinear partial differential equations by Lokenath Debnath, 3rd edition. I do not understand one step in the solution. Book shows how to solve the pde $(y-z)u_x+(z-x)u_y+(x-y)u_z=0$.

I follow everything, up to the step they say that $dx+dy+dz=0$.

I do not understand, why, given that $du=0$, then $dx+dy+dz=0$?

I also do not see where $x dx+y dy+ z dz=0$ came from.

Here is screen shot of the solution. It is not long.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

Thanks to answer below. But I still do not see how $x dx+y dy+ z dz=0$ came about. The book seems to use some other techniques to manipulate these characteristic equations without giving an explanation. For example on page 214 book gives

---

[image]

---

The answer below shows how book obtained relation of the form $dx+dy=0$, but I do not see how the other forms shown above can be obtained as well. Book must be doing some algebra, which it does not explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a  characteristic curve parametrized as $(x,y,z) = (X(t), Y(t), Z(t))$, we have

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = X'(t) = Y(t) - Z(t), \\ \frac{dy}{dt} =Y'(t)= Z(t) - X(t),\\ \frac{dz}{dt} =Z'(t) = X(t)-Y(t)$$

Hence, on a characteristic,

$$\frac{dx}{dt} +\frac{dy}{dt}+ \frac{dz}{dt} = 0$$

Similarly,

$$\begin{align}x\frac{dx}{dt} +y\frac{dy}{dt}+ z\frac{dz}{dt} &= x(y-z)+y(z-x)+z(x-y)\\ &= xy -xz + yz - xy +xz - yz \\ &= 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about these relations. Do you know how the second one $x dx+y dy+z dz=0$ also follows? i.e how does $dx+dy+dz=0$ implies $x dx+y dy+z dz=0$? I could not show this using those relations. If I multiply first eq by $x$, second by $y$, third by $z$ and add them, I do not get zero since now terms do not cancel.

Comment: @Nasser: The second equation is obtained in the same way.  I'll add the derivation to the answer.

Comment: The notation $dx+dy+dz = 0$ is just shorthand for the fact that the parametric representation of a characteristic curve $(X(t),Y(t), Z(t))$ has $X'(t) + Y'(t) + Z'(t) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, now I see. So to show that $dx+dy+dz=0$, you could have just used the same method you just used to show $x dx+y dy+z dz=0$? Which is that $dx+dy+dz=(y-z)+(z-x)+(x-y)$ which simplifies to zero. Thanks.